# accessing nested fields in handlebars when rendering from vert.x

Tags: handlebars.js, vert.x, server-side-rendering, html-rendering

I'm trying to render a page with an object having named fields:

```
{
    "context":{ 
          "greeting":"hello"
     }
}
```

And I'm rendering this with a very simple template:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            {{#with context}}
                <h1>{{greeting}} or {{this.greeting}}</h1>
            {{/with}}
                <h1>{{greeting}} or {{context.greeting}}</h1>
        </div>
    <div>the context is actually: {{context}} </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see above, I'm currently trying out several ways of rendering the `greeting` value. in earlier versions of this template I have tried them all one at a time too.

At the end of the template, I'm rendering the entirety of the `context` variable, just to ensure that the data I pass in is actually present. here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: template and result]

Having read the docs [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) and a tutorial [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-beginners-guide-to-handlebars/) I really can't see what I'm doing wrong, can someone clarify?

I should add that I'm using io.vertx:vertx-web-templ-handlebars:3.3.3 to render this

Below is the java method that returns this template. I'm using the Vert.x rendering engine.

```
private void handleStatus(RoutingContext ctx, TemplateEngine engine, String template)
{
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.put("greeting", "hello");
    ctx.put("context", json);

    engine.render(ctx, template, res ->
    {
        if (res.succeeded())
        {
            ctx.response().end(res.result());
        }
        else
        {
            ctx.fail(res.cause());
        }
    });
}
```

and here is where that method gets called from:

```
TemplateEngine engine = HandlebarsTemplateEngine.create();
statusHandler = new StatusHandler(vertx);
statusHandler.start();
deploymentHandler = new DeploymentHandler(vertx);

router.get("/monitor/apistatus").handler(ctx -> handleStatus(ctx, engine, "templates/apistatus.hbs"));
```

Comment: Your syntax is absolutely fine. Checked using - http://tryhandlebarsjs.com. The problem is mostly with the Handlebars initialisation and compilation code. It should ideally be `var source   = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
 var template = Handlebars.compile(source); var context = {sample Json data here};
var html    = template(context);` Check here for more details - http://handlebarsjs.com. Could you please share your init code?

Comment: I use the vert.x rendering engine, so it's not terribly exciting stuff I'm affraid. But I've edited my quesiton to include it anyways

Comment: I just noticed the line in your output `the context is actually: {"greeting":"hello"}`. Which means you are passing the data as a string and not as a JSON object. Else it would simply print `the context is actually: [object Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to 3.4.0, the Vert.x Web Handlebars template engine [did not work well with `JsonObject` and `JsonArray`](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/pull/509).

Upgrade to 3.4/3.5, or as a workaround, you could convert your `JsonObject` to a `Map`.

Comment: so thats why! thanks alot! I ended up rewriting my frontend as a react-app and serving raw json from the endpoint (luckily this is a fairly small project). but now I know if I ever feel like using handlebars again! :)